# How to loop through a database table to save every column as a single node?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a module, which loads company data from an external db to save this as content.

```
function example_create_nodes() {
// Get Data from external DATABASE
  db_set_active('db_wirdfit');
  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM wirdfit.wirdfit_data');
  db_set_active();

 foreach ($result as $row) {
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->type = "page";
  $node->title = $row->post_title;
  node_object_prepare($node);  //Set some default values

 // Try to set your custom field
  $node->field_id[$node->language][0]['value'] = $row->id;
  $node->field_post_content[$node->language][0]['value'] = $row->post_content;
  $node->field_post_author[$node->language][0]['value'] = $row->post_author;

  $node->date = 'complaint_post_date';
  $node->created = strtotime('complaint_post_date');

  $path = 'content/mytest-' . date('YmdHis');
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);
  print_r($row);
  node_save($node);

  }
```

That works but saved only one node from the the last row of my table.
How can I loop through the table and save every row as a single content page?

Thanks for help

Comment: I feel like this question has been posted multiple times. Was there something not satisfactory in the others? It sounds like you should be doing this with the migrate framework, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code shown in the question would cause a warning (*Creating default object from empty value*) when PHP executes `$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;` since `$node` isn't first initialized. PHP 8.0 would throw fatal error (*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "language" on null*).

The code needs to first initialize `$node`.
After the call to `node_save()`, when the node object isn't necessary anymore, it should set `$node->is_new` to `TRUE` and unset `$node->nid`. Differently, Drupal would think you are saving the same node.

```php
$node = (object) array();

foreach ($result as $row) {
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->type = "page";
  $node->title = $row->post_title;
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->field_id[$node->language][0]['value'] = $row->id;
  $node->field_post_content[$node->language][0]['value'] = $row->post_content;
  $node->field_post_author[$node->language][0]['value'] = $row->post_author;

  $path = 'content/mytest-' . date('YmdHis');
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);
  node_save($node);
  $node->is_new = TRUE;
  unset($node->nid);
}
```

I didn't set `$node->created`, which should be a Unix timestamp (and it's already set by `node_object_prepare()`), nor `$node->date`, which `node_object_prepare()` already sets to `$node->date = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s O')`;`. If you need to set those fields, you need to set them to the values Drupal expects (a timestamp and a date string).

Comment: That means the query you are executing, for some reason, it only returns a row. Probably, calling `db_set_active()` before getting all the data could be the culprit.

Comment: I tried your example, but it will only save one content from the first row of my table. It gave me an error . $node = array() has to be initialized after the foreach loop and it works. What will be the way, if i already have the content from the db and i only want to update the existing content?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially PHP - you are not initiating a new variable with each iteration of the loop. Start a new $node - otherwise you are writing to it over and over.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'page';
  ...
  $node = node_submit($node);
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `$node = new stdClass();`. It could use the same object, but set `$node->is_new` to `TRUE` and unset `$node->nid` before saving the node.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I have do this before but it didn`t work. With new stdclass() objekt  drupal saved for every row a new content but only with the data from the last row in my table. I think i need a sceond loop, but im really new to drupal and php ;-). Furthermore the content will also saved without $node=node_submit($node) => do i need this?